# GNU screen hangs application due to scroll blocking

Tags: gnu-screen

I run a critical application with lots of output under `screen`. Eventually it blocks. Investigation showed that the cause is `screen` which `unblock scrolling` with with `Ctrl-A q` or other tricks, ublocking the application at the same time. Is there way to prevent screen from blocking an application no matter how much it outputs?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird - for me, `screen` (on widely different hosts, different OS versions, different screen versions and so on) never blocks its applications, no matter how much they output. Eventually, when the scrollback buffer is full, old lines are cleared out, but the output keeps comming.

If you mention `ctrl-a q`, maybe take a look into the [flow control settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-flow-control), you can make screen ignore XON/XOFF (`ctrl-s`, `ctrl-q`) altogether...

EDIT: regarding your comment, I do believe that what you describe actually happens. I just wish to point out that it may not be `screen` that's causing it, or maybe it's because a weird combination with something else. I just now have `while true ; do date ; done` running in a `screen` - causing maximum spam. So far, many many thousands of lines have been written, and no blocking whatsoever. This is on a fresh, unmodified install of `screen` with default settings in a relatively fresh Debian 9.4 installation.

I have also tried the command you mentioned (`ssh -t user@host screen`) followed by the endless loop, and the same is true - no blocking after a long time.

Note that `ssh` has timeout features on keyboard (console) inactivity; maybe those are to blame?

Comment: This indeed happens. I run the application from bash, which runs from `ssh -t host screen -dR scr_name`. The application writes its log, so I can check it really hangs, not only screen output. After  screen unblocking it resumes logging as well a s console output.